# solrnet query to get filter for boolean type field indexed to solr

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, solrnet

I have indexed products with stocks availability.

It means if products have stock then stock availability field has value "true" otherwise "false".

Now if I select any category, on Category page I want a filter for "Excluding Out of Stock", same as flip kart do.

I can do this in solr?

How can I perform solrnet query to get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the following thing and pass a solrnet query and it works for me.

```
 List<ISolrQuery> _solrQuery = new List<ISolrQuery>();
_solrQuery.Add(new SolrQueryByField("StockAvailability", "true"));
```